# Unable to determine and print out truncation error from int to float implicit cast

Tags: c, casting

Learning C with a book. In my book, a similar code should have yielded "3.000000" as truncation error. The book is a bit older, still on C99 standard. What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    float f;

    scanf("%d", &i); // 123456789
    f = i; // implicit type cast

    printf("int: %d with size %d\n", i, sizeof(i)); // int: 123456789 with size 4
    printf("float: %f with size %d\n", f, sizeof(f)); // float: 123456792.000000 with size 4

    printf("error: %f with size %d\n", f-i, sizeof(f-i)); // error 0.000000 with size 4

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `%d` is the wrong format string for `sizeof()`, whose type is `size_t` not `int`.  Make it `%zu` instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks, that works. I am a bit confused, because my book actually explained the implicit arithmetic conversion that should happen at f-i, but then apparently makes this error. Confusing, but now it makes sense. Thank you! Add it as an answer if you like, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `0.000000` is correct. C99 6.3.1.8p1 says:

> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is float, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is float.

So in `f-i`, the `i` is converted to `float`, yielding the same value as `f`. I am not sure how your book's compiler could have got `3.000000`.

If you really want to see the truncation error, do `(double)f  - i`.

Comment: And I am right assuming that in `(double)f - i` both operands get casted to double, only now we actually see the difference, because f was casted into integer with a truncation error earlier, and now double preserves complete accuracy of the whole int in i and the truncation error in f, right?

Comment: @Felix: That's right.

Comment: However, note p2 of the same section "The values of floating operands and of the results of floating expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby." -- so the operands (and the operation) may happen in greater precision (and give a non-zero result) if the implementation finds that easier.  In particular, compilers for 8086/8087 (non-64 bit x86) often do everything in 80-bit precision.